# Rosdep not finding packages that are in index.yaml

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am have ros-kinetic installed in Ubuntu 16.04. I cloned a couple of packages into my workspace and ran rosdep to get their dependencies. I ran rosdep from the root of my workspace using this line

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro ${ROS_DISTRO} -y --as-root pip:no --skip-keys="gazebo"
```

Rosdep returns with a bunch of missing pacakages. The missing packages in my case are listed below.

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-sick-tim
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-socketcan-bridge
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-canopen-chain-node
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-base-local-planner
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-robot-localization
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-effort-controllers
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-turtlebot-interactive-markers
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-um7
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-ros-controllers
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-gmapping
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-costmap-2d
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-turtlebot-rviz-launchers
dpkg-query: no packages found matching python-opencv
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-socketcan-interface
dpkg-query: no packages found matching python-shapely
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-can-msgs
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-turtlebot-gazebo
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-joint-limits-interface
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-turtlebot-teleop
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-transmission-interface
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-turtlebot-navigation
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-tf2-sensor-msgs
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-realsense-camera
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-pointcloud-to-laserscan
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-hardware-interface
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-uuid-msgs
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-turtlebot-simulator
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-controller-manager
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-amcl
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-realtime-tools
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-nav-core
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-move-base
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-hector-gazebo-plugins
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-usb-cam
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-turtlebot-description
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-move-base-msgs
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-teb-local-planner
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-turtlebot-capabilities
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-map-server
```

Most of these packages are found in the ros distro index file. I am able to install them manually using apt-get. Why is rosdep failing to find them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269467/rosdep-not-finding-packages-that-are-in-index.yaml/) by [prarobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3114/prarobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-08-23**:
Is that the full output from `rosdep`? I usually get a string of `dpkg-query` like that, and then `rosdep` installs all of the packages.

**Comment by [prarobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3114/prarobo/) on 2017-08-24**:
That was the problem. I had misspelled a different package that prevented rosdep from continuing and installing more stuff. I knew about the misspelled package but didn't realize that was causing other packages from being installed. Thanks for your suggestion. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case some package is mispelled or if there is some other reason preventing rosdep from installing some package. That could also prevent if from installing some valid packages in the list. Fixing other errors that rosdep detected fixed this problem.

---

Originally posted by [prarobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3114/prarobo/) with karma: 35 on 2017-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1